# Heroku Restore Not working...!

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku

I am trying to restore a local db.dump file into my heroku app..!!

using:-

```
heroku pg:backups restore 'https://s3.amazonaws.com/somebucket/db.dump' 

DATABASE mydb
```

But I am getting a error :-

```
An Error has occured and your backup did not finish
Please run 'heroku logs --ps pg-backups' for details.
```

When I run that It doesnt show any logs.

Please help I am new to RoR

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the source of `dump` is correct & you have made the application down while restoring the db. Try accessing logs after sometime.

In case your logs are empty and error still persists, you need to contact heroku support. There is not much that you can do for this.